# Jquery each element loop inside only parent dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This dynamic content can be different height, different paragraph.

I want make all of these heights to equal biggest content height.

```
    <ul class="parent">
    <li class="child"> dynamic content</li>
    <li class="child"> dynamic content</li>
    <li class="child"> dynamic content</li>
    </ul>

// this height could be different

    <ul class="parent">
    <li class="child"> dynamic content</li>
    <li class="child"> dynamic content</li>
    </ul>
// and this too.
```

I wrote code like below. But that code affect all child. 
Can you give me any suggestion?

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".whiteModelContainer").find(".whiteModel").each(function () {

            maxHeight = $(this).height()>maxHeight? $(this).height() : maxHeight;
    });
    $(".whiteModelContainer").find(".whiteModel").height(maxHeight);
});
```

It's resolved. Thanks Barmar

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: How do the `whiteModelContainer` and `whiteModel` classes related to the HTML you showed?

Comment: HTML version has included so long term. So i want to tell like this example. they are like each other

Comment: There's no `div` between `parent` and `child`.

Comment: it's not problem. your firtst comment verry helpfully. i will fix it. thanks again

Comment: oh, sorry i didn't know this rule. now i accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the parents, resetting `maxHeight` to `0` for each of them, then loop over the children within it to calculate the max. Then you want to set the height of all those children.

```
$(".parent").each(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(".child", this).each(function() {
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
    }).height(maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: What a great answer. Thank you very much. Now i will understand absolutely.  God bless you :)

Comment: You might want to add a closing parenthesis for `Math.max` :)